# How do I re-enable a display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, settings

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 as a main OS in my laptop. I had deactivated my external display in display settings because I was moving my PC to my WiFi router (WiFi drivers weren't working, that fixed) but now I cant find the option to turn my display back on. In fact, the display doesn't even show up under that section of the settings. I would like to be able to use this display I've got, that's only compatible with my PC.

I am a newbie at Ubuntu, if you give me a command to type in, please BE VERY SPECIFIC.

Edit: The monitor has previously worked. I know it did.

Comment: Is it possible that you have your BIOS configured to only allow the internal display?

Comment: No. I haven't you he the BIOS since I needed to activate my discrete graphics cards for the second display when I first got it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I feel stupid. While going into the bios of my laptop to edit some settings, I noticed that my discrete graphics (the ones that control external displays) was turned off. Before I posted the question, I am 100% positive that option was enabled. Ubuntu must've gone into the bios and disabled them. So, if you have display troubles like me, check the bios.